# Setting external packages to be loaded for a R project?

Tags: r, package

I'm building a model that predicts the sales of a grocery brand besides doing some exploratory work. Couple of packages need to be loaded every time the need arises to modify the dates or run a regression on the training set. Specifically I want the `tidyr`, `lubridate`, `e1071` and the `readr` packages to be loaded every time I open the project since running the library commands from the top of the R script is always annoying. Without editing the .RProfile file (that corresponds to global settings), how do I set these packages to be loaded on startup for only this project?

Comment: if your project written as a package, then you are done. Please note that, this package can be only for your project.

Comment: No, its not a package development project..

Comment: I understand your question. But you can write your project functions as your own package (especially if your project contains many functions). It is will be so convenient to you every time need to develop your project.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good idea. But cannot this be done by editing the .Rproj file? Its only these 5 packages that are the most important right now...

Comment: I tried that before but I really could not and then use package. What about if you write one line code that load all these package for you at once.